# Can’t see WD My Cloud from a Windows 10 computer while Windows 7 computer can see it fine

Tags: windows-10, networking

I have an WD My Cloud on my netwoork, one computer with Windows 7 instaled can see it properly. Another computer with Windows 10 can't see it. Group on all devices is named as WORKGROUP, also Windows 7 computer can see Windows 10 computer and vice versa.

All computers are hooked to same router via cable. I can't find what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the advice online at https://community.wd.com/t/windows-10-cant-see-my-cloud-workaround/142986 ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your control panel, open up Programs & Features, then select Turn Windows Features On or Off.

Place a checkmark in the box labeled SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support. Restart computer.

If it is already installed, remove the checkmark and restart. Then go back and place a checkmark and restart again to reinstall.

Here is a more detailed link from WD regarding the issue:
[WD Not Showing in Network Folder](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4155)